# Converting program between GCC version 7.2.0 and GCC version 4.9.2?

Tags: c, gcc

I wrote a pretty extensive C program on my personal laptop which is running Ubuntu with GCC version 7.2.0 and it worked well enough. However, when I passed those same .c and .h files to a different computer running Debian with GCC version 4.9.2 to compile, I ran into runtime errors where it isn't exiting as it should.

I thought at first, it might have been an issue with the `-std` flag, so I set them both to `make` with `-std=gnuc99` but that didn't solve anything. I know I didn't change anything in any files, so it couldn't be any issue of inadvertently changing program logic. Unless bundling the project folder into a .tar can change something.

The compiler throws no errors and only a couple of warnings about unused variables that I've already known about.

All of that was a lead-up to ask this:
What are/where can I find the differences between those two versions of GCC and is there any tool I can use to convert code so that it will work in 4.9.2 like it does with 7.2.0?

I'm fine with rewriting code, if need be, but I don't even know where to start?
Right now I'm just throwing trace statements in order to pinpoint where exactly it's making a mess of itself and I'll edit if pertinent information makes itself available.

Comment: The "conversion" process would involve fixing bugs leading to undefined behaviors you have in your program.

Comment: To start, turn on `-Wmost`, carefully consider all the warnings you get, and then turn on `-Wall`. After that, you are in a good debugging situation: You have both a working version of the program (the version compiled with 7.2.0) and a non-working version. Find some input that reproducibly causes the non-working one to fail. Then you can instrument the program to show its internal state as it proceeds, after which you look for differences between them.

Comment: certainly sounds like UB to me. What does "isn't exiting as it should" mean? Seg faulting? If so, run it under gdb, and when it crashes you can at least look at the call stack and examine variables.

Comment: "My program doesn't work as expected! Must be an issue with the compiler." No, it's far more likely to be a bug in your code.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: gcc 7.2.0 attempts to conform to the C11 standard; I don't think 4.9.2 did.  Further, I suspect that 7.2.0 has likely fixed some bugs from earlier versions that caused them to behave in non-conforming fashion.  I don't see why you assume the fault is with the program rather than the compiler.

Comment: @supercat First of all it's the golden rule - always assume fault with the code rather than with a compiler. Second - there is no compilation errors. Third - the OP used `std=gnuc99`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I enforced that gnuc99 standard in the hopes, that maybe the two systems were defaulting to different standards and that would fix it. Is there something weird about it? I admit, I'm dreadfully ignorant about the differences in versions of compilers.

Comment: @yano It essentially kept running forever, thus I'm assuming something was failing every check throughout the entire program.

Comment: @melpomene I do often assume I did something wrong. But I'm using the SAME EXACT code between two versions of GCC and getting different behaviour.

Comment: @neutralboolean you couldn't describe a symptom of UB better than what you just said. If you have a lot of code, UB can be tough to track down, especially if it's not crashing. Examine the extreme cases on the loops where it runs forever. Tough to say, you haven't provided much to go on. Changing up your compiler flags for gcc 7.2.0 could very well change the behavior also.

Comment: @neutralboolean Yes, that's how bugs work in C. Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: So this is ultimately a case of slowly changing things until it works?

Comment: Sounds like a standard debugging issue to me: The code doesn't work as expected, so you need to figure out where your mental model diverges from reality. Possible tools include: staring at the code, adding logging, running it in a debugger, etc.

Comment: Basically. You say it loops forever. First place I'd start is the loop condition. Is that part of an array? Allocated memory? Is it an `int` that could possibly be overflowing? Stack Overflow used to have a wonderful collection of undefined behavior in `c` in their documentation section and then they inexplicably removed it.

Comment: Given that gcc's efforts at optimization have generally gone in the direction of becoming more aggressive except in cases where they can be clearly and unambiguously demonstrated to violate the Standard, failure of code to work on newer versions may point to UB, but failure of code to work on older versions could just as easily be a result of illegitimate "optimizations" which have since been fixed.

Comment: Without the code for an MCVE ([MCVE]), there’s not a lot we can do to help you

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your help. But I'm not entirely sure how to close this. The "answer" to my question was a matter of just working my way through the program again. Would that be acceptable as an answer, or should I flag a mod to close this for me?

Comment: Please either make an answer or delete the question yourself. The actual solution is, as several comments have noted, to remove/avoid undefined behaviour. Going through the code, cleaning up anything weird, fixing all warnings, including those which occur when using strict warnings, ... All that. Consider using a file-diff tool to help you remember all the changes.

Comment: @neutralboolean: You can simply delete the question.